# Build docker image with --pull option

Tags: docker, quarkus

Let's take the initial dockerfile proposed by Quarkus in order to build a docker image with a native application:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.6
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I have the need to not consider any kind cache while building.
So, using plain docker command, something like: `docker build --pull --no-cache .`

But looking at Quarkus' docker documentation: https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image#DockerOptions
I don't find any useful option.

Is it possible force image pull with the following extension: [quarkus-container-image-docker](https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image#docker) ?

Looking at this class: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/container-image/container-image-docker/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/container/image/docker/deployment/DockerProcessor.java

I wasn't able to recognize any part in which is handling these options

Comment: Hi, this sounds like a reasonable feature request. Mind opening an issue in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues?

Comment: Sounds good to me, I opened this issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/33866

Thank you for your feedback @geoand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/33876 becomes available in Quarkus (likely 3.2), then you'll be able to add the following to `application.properties` to satisfy your use case:

`quarkus.docker.additional-args=--pull,--no-cache`